# How to identify what probability distribution this is?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

in the context of a very long derivation (variational inference), by grouping the constant terms, I arrive at the following form that should be a probability distribution:

$$
p(x) = C x^{-a} \exp\left\{{\frac{b}{x^2} - x}\right\}
$$

(this probability distribution should be an approximation of a posteriori parameter; it's derived via variational inference, mean field assumption)

Any ideas of the name of this probability distribution?

Another issue is: how to find a parameter range for which this probability distribution might be a valid one?

Comment: This function does not seem integrable at 0, which is annoying for a PDF.

Comment: Yeah, what makes you think this is a pdf at all? Did you obtain it emprically?

Comment: I am doing a variational inference derivation (mean field). This should be the approximated distribution of a parameter a posteriori.

Comment: What support do you expect? E.g. for $a=1, b=-1$ it looks that it could be a PDF on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: yes, $b$ can definitely be negative

Comment: Do you have real data? If you have, maximum likelihood estimation may help you find specific values of parameters a,b. Because in most of the time, the value of parameters also help to determine the specific distribution. Here, based on what you say, the correct term to use here is that what "family distribution" does it belong to?

Comment: @lzstat : this is a toy problem, so I will generate the data myself. In this case I am using variational inference to obtain that specific distribution. The data is already contained in the placeholders `a`, `b` and `C`. I already know the value of those parameters, but to simplify I decided to aggregate the values into the symbols `a`,`b` and `C`.